# Smarten up my jquery tabbed browsing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've put together a very simple tabbed browser which you can see here
http://jsfiddle.net/zandergrin/sN2Eu/

I'm just wondering if there was a way to smarten up the script so that all the numbering is handled automatically - ie I can add a new tab and wouldn't need to add new javascript.

I know I can do it with jquery ui, but a) I'm trying to lkeep it super lightweight and, more importantly, b) I'm trying to learn!!

Thanks - I'm pretty basic on my javascript so any explanations would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a comman class to each tab so you can select all of them and a unique id that is also the value in the `href` of the links.
Also add a common class to all the links..

```
<div class="tab-nav">
     <ul>
         <li><a href="#tab1" class="tabclick active">Overview</a></li>
         <li><a href="#tab2" class="tabclick">Specs</a></li>
         <li><a href="#tab3" class="tabclick">More Info</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>


<div id="tab1" class="tab">
    <p>content1</p>
</div>

<div id="tab2" class="tab" style="display: none">
    <p>content2</p>
</div>

<div id="tab3" class="tab" style="display: none">
    <p>content3</p>
</div>
```

and your javascript now can be

```
function tabActions(e) {
    // e.preventDefault(); // stop default browser action of link will not add the hash to the url

    var targetId = $(this).attr('href'); // extract the value in the href (the #tab1 for example)

    $('.tabclick').removeClass('active'); // remove the active class from all links (find them by their common class)
    $(this).addClass('active'); // add it to the currently clicked link

    $('.tab').hide(); // find all tabs (by the common class) and hide them
    $(targetId).show(); // show the current tab 
};

$('.tabclick')
    .click(tabActions) // bind handler
    .filter(function(){ // find the link that points to the hash in the url
        return this.hash == window.location.hash;
    })
    .click(); // manually trigger click on it
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/sN2Eu/3/

Comment: this looks perfect - andt I'll try it later, but I sense a tick incoming. Thanks!

Comment: just one issue before the shiny green tick cometh - this seems to stop the url updating with the hash location (so when I click tab2 the url stays the same - doesn't become myurl.com/mypage.html#tab2)which prevents the window location bit from working

Comment: @JorgeLuisBorges, the `location.hash` part is only needed for the first time. All the subsequent click are handled from the actual element that was clicked.. in any case, you can comment out the `e.preventDefault();` line so that the hash will be updated in the url on each click.

Comment: hmm - the purpose of the hash is so that people can link directly to the url with the hash and it switches to the right tab. Uncommenting that line doesn't seem to enable this

Comment: @JorgeLuisBorges, worn language usage.. i mean to comment it , not uncomment it..

Comment: sorry - me too! commenting it doesn't enable going straight to the right tab using a correctly hashed url

Comment: @JorgeLuisBorges, you are absolutely right.. i have an error in the code.. updating answer

Comment: @JorgeLuisBorges answer is updated (*changed the last part of the script*)